# How to extract or cast DATE in MS access SQL?

Tags: ms-access

MS Access has `datetime` datatype which is very inconvenient because other databases do distinguish between `date` and `time`.

I am querying MS Access and need to get the `date` ONLY
How can I do this, how to cast `DATE` to the `datetime`field ?

The following query throws an error

```
SELECT DATE (birth_date), fname, lname 
FROM ms_access_table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
SELECT 
    DateValue(birth_date) As BDate, 
    TimeValue(birth_date) As BTime, 
    fname, 
    lname 
FROM 
    ms_access_table
```